# How do I put a @page using StyleSheet in itext

Tags: css, itext, stylesheet

I'd like to put a css programmatically using StyleSheet class in IText.
I don't know how I can create it.

Any idea?

CSS

```
@page {
 size: landscape;
 counter-increment: page; 
 @bottom-right { padding-right : 20px;
 content: "P&#225;gina " counter(page);
}
```

Java

```
StyleSheet page = new StyleSheet();

HashMap<K, V> mapPage = new HashMap();
mapPage.put("size", "landscape");
mapPage.put("counter-increment", "page");

page.loadStyle("@page", mapPage);
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the rendering of a PDF based on whether someone is viewing it in their browser or printing it?

Comment: Yes, I used a Freemarker template in order to create the style. So configured the pdf document with that style.